# ElasticSearch retrieve only list elements that match a term within single document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, term-query

Given this document structure.

```
{
   "title":"Lord of the rings",
   "id":"123abc",
   "pages":[
      {
         "pageNumber":1,
         "content":"Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
      },
      {
         "pageNumber":2,
         "content":"dolor sit dolor sit dolor sit"
      }
   ]
}
```

and this query

```
{
   "query":{
      "match":{
         "pages.content":"lorem"
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a way that elastic can give me something like this as a result:

```
{
   "title":"Lord of the rings",
   "id":"123abc",
   "pages":[
      {
         "pageNumber":1,
         "content":"Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
      }
   ]
}
```

So in case I have hundreds of pages I will only get those that match my term?

I though about creating a index for pages, but how would I get all the meta data from the document? Should this metadata be copied in all pages document from the same "book" lets say?
What's the best approach in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, documents sharing some common metadata is quite normal (and often necessary) in NoSQL datastores. As to an alternative approach, you could use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-highlighting) or even some [painless scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-walkthrough.html) but I'd recommend something along the lines of:

```
POST pages/_doc
{
  "book": {
    "title": "Lord of the rings",
    "id": "123abc",
    "metadata": {
      "num_of_pages": 300
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "content": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
  }
}

POST pages/_doc
{
  "book": {
    "title": "Lord of the rings",
    "id": "123abc",
    "metadata": {
      "num_of_pages": 300
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "pageNumber": 2,
    "content": "dolor sit dolor sit dolor sit"
  }
}
```

And then

```
GET pages/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "page.content": "lorem"
    }
  }
}
```

which is much simpler & scales reasonably well.

Comment: This also makes me think about a problem. The way elastic search creates the score of a match query (tf+idf). Think about the next situation

Book A = 100 pages
Book B = 100 pages

Search query: "lorem"

Book A has a single page where this term appears 10 times lets say. So 99 pages no term, 1 page 10 times this term.

Book B has like 20 pages where this term appears with a maximum of 6 times in a single page.

Elastic will give me the page of Book A as the highest score but book B will fit better into the search cause it has more frecuency overall .

How to manage this?

Comment: I suppose it would but you're interested in pages rather than books, aren't you? That's how I understood your query. Or are you looking for term frequency across the whole book? That's a wholly different use case.

Comment: lets say that i have both use cases, Sometimes I need to know what book then sometimes i need to know which page's of a book.